# Is it healthy for a cat to regularly eat cheese?

Tags: cats, diet

My kitten Mickey is addicted to cheese and will not stop meowing until we feed him. We give him about a handful a day. Is that healthy for a one-year-old cat?

Comment: My sassy loves raisins which was amazing when I saw him actually eat one. I also give him a little bit of cheese which yes he really loves.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While kittens generally can handle dairy products, adult cats usually can't. Feeding cats dairy products can lead to digestive issues resulting in diarrhea or vomiting.

Simply stopping giving into the kittens demands would most likely stop this behavior as the cat will learn that their meowing doesn't result in a reward.

Backing information on dairy and cats: [Human Foods that are Dangerous for Cats](http://www.petmd.com/cat/emergency/poisoning-toxicity/e_ct_human_food_poisoning) (petmd.com)

Comment: Thanks! I will try to stop but he goes absolutely wild and starts jumping on me. Is there a way I can stop this behavior?

Comment: Ignoring the cats behavior for a while should work. Your cat probably has associated his actions with getting what he wants, so as long as he associates the two, he will continue doing it. Ignoring his behavior should stop it eventually.

Comment: Note that cheese is [low on lactose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactose_intolerance#Dairy_products). I doubt that it is enough to pose a problem.

Comment: @Baarn that goes for traditionally made hard cheeses, but some industrial processes may perform differently at breaking the lactose down. Some cheeses are labeled as lactose-free or, even better, *naturally* lactose-free, though; I would stick with the latter category to be safe.

Answer (score 7):

Cheese contains lots of fat, which is a tasty treat for a cat, but it should really be just a treat. I think you probably want to reduce that quantity a bit, maybe to a fifth of that and make it a more special snack instead and look for alternate treats, such as hard treats that will keep his teeth in good shape.