# How to feed stray/wild cat

Tags: cats, feeding, veterinarian, feral

I do not have a pet, but every other day a cat comes to us for food. This has been going on for a month now. In our part of the world (subcontinent), the stray cats/dogs will eat just about anything.

I currently give her a cup of milk 2 times a day and she drinks it without much fuss, and occasionally I give her some pieces of meat.

I read that adult cats should not be given milk or wheat products such as bread. Is this valid for all cats or just the house cats. Meat is quite expensive, and if milk is not to be given, then what other food could be the option? Could I give her raw or boiled eggs?

I've seen her catch mice, so she isn't completely dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not give any milk to any animal(Not only cats but all animals will get ill if you do give milk or milk products)It is better to give clean water and dry cat food.

Feeding dry catfood is safe for most of the wildlife like birds-rodents-foxes-dogs.

If the cat do  hunt it will only need catfood as a supplement to the prey it eats.

You need to get the cat spayed or neutered so you need to talk to animal protection in your area to get this done.

Related: [Cat and cow's milk (whole milk) -- A feral cat knows what's good for it, right?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15674/cat-and-cows-milk-whole-milk-a-feral-cat-knows-whats-good-for-it-right)

Comment: By dry cat food you mean the commercially available cat food?

Comment: yes it is one of the avaliable types of cat food you can get in many shops.