# What 'Special Occasion' Food Can I Feed My Cat?

Tags: cats, treats

My cat goes in for surgery tomorrow, which makes tonight possibly her last night on this earth. I want to give her something special for dinner. She loves chicken and poultry in general, and also cheese. I was thinking of just giving her some, finely diced chicken, and some small cheese bits - but are there any other recommendations of something special I could give her?

Comment: what surgery is your cat having? I hope she is ok

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. What's the link between surgery and last day on earth? What ailment is your cat suffering from?

Comment: Related [Is it healthy for a cat to regularly eat cheese?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/34/is-it-healthy-for-a-cat-to-regularly-eat-cheese)

Comment: How is your cat doing?  I hope everything is okay!

Comment: Soneval: she had a very complicated surgery to remove an enormous mass from her liver. She ALSO had a shunt going around the liver. She ALSO had a history of blood not clotting properly. All this led the vet to not really know what to expect once he 'got in there' so to speak so it was very exploratory and uncertain, so I was just making sure that if it WAS her last night, it would be a good one.

All: she is doing well, however! Currently under observation at the clinic for a few days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be hard for us to say what is "special" or not.  We don't really know your cat.  We don't know her likes or dislikes or the kinds of treats or food you normally feed.  If you were to be asked the same question for yourself, it would vastly differ from what my answer would be for myself.  Probably the best thing to do is to give her the food that she goes bonkers over.

I know for my cat, any time chicken is out on the table, I burn off the dinner calories just trying to keep her away.  If what you said above is what she loves, then I am sure she will enjoy it to the max.  Maybe even give her a larger portion than usual.  Extra treats of her favorite kind.

Let her cuddle up or play with you when it would otherwise annoy you after a day of working.  Treat the night to be all about your kitty.  Let her feel the love.  It isn't so much about getting her special food as much as it is knowing that you prepared her something she loves from your heart and spent quality time to make sure if this were to be her last night, it was memorable for you AND her.

Take lots of pictures, stay up a little later to watch a movie just so she would stay in your lap longer.  Enjoy your time together.

Comment: I love this answer - I'd also add - take lots of videos of her.

Comment: I'd say some canned tuna, use a strainer to rinse with water to remove excess salts, but I've never seen a cat that DIDN'T Like tuna or salmon. I hope she does well, so sorry. Try not to be worried, cats can sense human emotion.

Comment: Definitely the right answer I think. Of course I wasn't simply going to give her a special dinner and call it a day, she had a wonderful evening altogether, but I did wind up giving her raw chicken and cheese bits mixed into her favorite wet food. Ultimately the correct answer here, in retrospect, is that I would know better than anyone!

Comment: @PeregrineStudios how did your cat do through surgery?

Comment: I posted a comment on the actual question - she's recovering well under observation!

Answer (score 3):

It's better not to give something special to your cat before surgery. Even us humans have hospital food for a reason. Stick to it's regular diet in order for her digestive system not to be disturbed and let's hope that she will have many more nights to enjoy special treats described in other answers!

And show her love! That is the most important.